# Excel JETT Page Orientation

Tags: excel, jett

Does JETT support page orientation? When printing portrait the report spans two pages. When printing landscape the report spans one page and this the desired results.

Comment: Just change the Page Setup orientation to Landscape in the desired sheet in the Template spreadsheet.

Comment: How is this done in the template?

Comment: Through Excel itself: Page Layout -> Orientation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm wanting to do the orientation in the Jett script. I'm wanting to automate the scheduling of the report and deliver the landscape oriented report the user.